# Integral values of $a$ in Trigonometric Inequality

Tags: functions, trigonometry, solution-verification

> If $\displaystyle a\cos(t)+\frac{a\cos(3t)}{2}\leq 3$ for all real $t$. Then integral value of $a$ is

What I try : $\displaystyle a\cos(t)+\frac{a\bigg(4\cos^3(t)-3\cos(t)\bigg)}{2}\leq 3$

$4a\cos^3(t)-a\cos(t)\leq 6$

$a\cos(t)\bigg(\cos^2(t)-1\bigg)\leq 6$

$\displaystyle a\leq \frac{6}{\cos^3(t)-\cos(t)}$

Now let $\cos(t)=u,$ Then $u\in[-1,1]$

Then $\displaystyle f(u)=u^3-u$, Then $f'(u)=3u^2-1$

Then for maximum and minimum , put $f'(u)=0$

So we have $\displaystyle u=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

And $\displaystyle f''(u)=6u$

Now we want $f(u)=\min$, which occur when $\displaystyle u=-1$

So we have $\displaystyle a\leq \frac{6}{f(u)}\leq \frac{6}{0}=\infty$

But answer given as $2$ integral values of $a$

Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After getting$$4a\cos^3(t)-a\cos(t)\leqslant6,$$you should have deduced that $\cos(t)\bigl(\color{red}4\cos^2(t)-1\bigr)\leqslant6$. Anyway,  since you always have $-1\leqslant\cos(t)\leqslant1$, what matters here is to study the function $4x^3-x$ with $x\in[-1,1]$. And the maximum of this function is $3$, which is obtained when $x=1$. So, the maximum of $4a\cos^3(t)-a\cos(t)$ is $3a$ and, if you want this maximum to be $6$, you should take $a=2$.